# Слайдер изображений. Проверка src

Tags: javascript, jquery

Некорректно проверяется условие. По сути это даже не слайдер, я как бы просто меняю src у класса img.

Как вообще лучше делать слайдер изображений?

```js
$(function(){
let imgSlider = $('.img')[0];
        let radioBtn = $('.radio');
        let images = ['https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1652143/pub_5cc006793456ac00b39424e7_5cc006eb20749800b5af02ce/scale_1200','https://ipmoney.info/images/load/ssylki.jpg'];
        radioBtn.on('change',function(){
            if(imgSlider.src = images[0])
                {
                    imgSlider.src = images[1];
                    console.log(1);
                }
            else
                {
                    imgSlider.src = images[0];
                    console.log(2);
                }
     });
});
```

```css
.img_container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img_container">
        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1652143/pub_5cc006793456ac00b39424e7_5cc006eb20749800b5af02ce/scale_1200" alt="" class="img">
        <input type="radio" name="1" id="radio1" class="radio" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="1" id="radio2" class="radio">
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: А чем вас не устраивают готовые слайдеры?

Comment: Всю голову сломал, пока не заметил `if(imgSlider.src = images[0])`

Comment: Я познаю мир js и jquery. Я хочу понять и разобраться, а не искать готовые варианты. В открытом доступе более сложные и продвинутые слайдеры, которые мне пока что не нужны.